# How can I make the code for my word guessing game shorter?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning Python last night and I tried to write a simple guessing game with the option to change the guess word. I was wondering how I could simplify it.

```
guess_word = "Giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 4
out_of_guesses = False

Question = input("Do you want to change guess word?")
if Question == "Yes":
    guess_word = input("Please input new word:")
    while guess != guess_word and not out_of_guesses:
        if guess_count < guess_limit:
            guess = input("Please make a guess: ")
            guess_count = guess_count + 1
        else:
            out_of_guesses = True
    if out_of_guesses:
        print("Out of Guesses, You Lose")
    else:
        print("You win, the word was " + guess_word + "!")
else:
    while guess != guess_word and not out_of_guesses:
        if guess_count < guess_limit:
            guess = input("Please make a guess: ")
            guess_count = guess_count + 1
        else:
            out_of_guesses = True
    if out_of_guesses:
        print("Out of Guesses, You Lose")
    else:
        print("You win, the word was " + guess_word + "!")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this code as below. Only set the guess word if `question == Yes`. Then run the loop while there are still guesses left. This takes advantage of the fact that an `int` is considered as `True` if it is not `0`, so while there are guesses are left the loop condition will be evaluated as `True`. Once `guesses` is `0` the while loop condition will evaluate as `False` and the loop will terminate.

While in the loop we check if the input matches the word, if so then we print "You win..." and we `break` the loop. If the input did not match the word then we decrease the guess count by 1 and loop starts again.

When `guesses` reaches `0` loop will terminate. The `else` condition of the loop is only executed if the loop terminated without a break. So if they win, we call break and the else of the loop is not executed. However if they run out of guesses the loop will terminate successfully without break and else statement will be run and print "You ran out...".

```
guess_word = "Giraffe"
guesses = 4

Question = input("Do you want to change guess word?")
if Question == "Yes":
    guess_word = input("Please input new word:")

while guesses:
    if input("Please make a guess: ") == guess_word:
        print("You win, the word was " + guess_word + "!")
        break
    guesses -= 1
else:
    print("You ran out of guesses so you lose")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guess_word = "Giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 4
out_of_guesses = False

Question = input("Do you want to change guess word?")
if Question == "Yes":
    guess_word = input("Please input new word:")

while guess != guess_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Please make a guess: ")
        guess_count = guess_count + 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of Guesses, You Lose")
else:
    print("You win, the word was " + guess_word + "!")
```

Super easy! just eliminate all the duplicative guessing logic if the guess word is changed. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should use a `for` loop when you know the upper limit of when your code should stop. It also makes it more legible when you remove some unnecessary variables.

```
guess_word = "Giraffe"
guess_limit = 4

answer = input("Do you want to change guess word?").lower()

if answer == "yes":
    guess_word = input("Please input new word:")

if answer == 'no':
    for i in range(guess_limit):
        guess = input("Please make a guess: ")
        if guess == guess_word:
            print("You win, the word was " + guess_word + "!")
            break
        if i == guess_limit - 1:
            print("Out of Guesses, You Lose")
```